# Creating large numbers of command buttons and writing more efficiently

Tags: excel, commandbutton, memory-efficient, vba

I am working on an Excel VBA project with 300 rows that will be filled with outgoing orders daily. There are going to be 4 command buttons and various macros for each row. The first is "TIME IN" this will log when the order started as well as place the words "IN PROGRESS" in a column on sheet 1. The next button will be "TIME OUT" when clicked this will log time of completion place the word "COMPLETE" in the proper column and move the entire row to a separate workbook. The third button will be "HOLD" this will log the time a hold is placed on loading, move the entire row to sheet 3 of the same workbook and put the words "PARTIAL HOLD" in the appropriate column. The fourth button will be on sheet 3 it will be a "RESUME" button. This button will send the row from sheet 3 back to sheet 1 with the words "IN PROGRESS" in the appropriate column. My question is, is it possible to make these buttons and respective macros in bulk or do I have to make each individual button and macro that goes along with it? If it is possible to do it in bulk could you please tell me how. Below is an example of the code for the command buttons and the correlated macros for each button that I have created so far individually. All of them have the same basic code and macro associated. Thank you for helping me write more efficiently.
Command button

```
Private Sub HOLD1_Click()
Sheet1.Cells(5, 17).Value = Format$(Now, "hh:nn:ss")
HOLD_1
End Sub
```

Macro

```
Sub HOLD_1()
'
' HOLD_1 Macro
'

'
Range("M5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PARTIAL HOLD"
Range("M6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying you are planning to create 4 buttons for each row, so in total more than 1000 buttons.

Comment: Adding 4 buttons per row, for many rows will make everything very slow, just because of the objects themselves, never mind their functionality. When I had to make similar functionality, I would create "clickable cells" - if columns `A to K` contain data, I'd make columns `L to O` clickable (distinct background color as well), using `SelectionChange()` event allows you to determine the coordinates of each cell, and to build specific actions depending on current row. This approach is much more effective and scalable

Comment: Yes Storax if I were to do buttons it would be around 1200 total buttons maybe more, but thanks to Paul I will work on doing the clickable cells and see if it is possible to still have the functions I am trying to use in the overall document. Thank you.

Comment: Paul with your suggestion, how do I get it so that if I click a cell in column K, the macro will only run in the corresponding row. Example I was originally doing a TIME IN button. This button when clicked would log time in and place the words "IN PROGRESS" in another column on the same row. I can make the clickable cells for an entire column run a macro but I don't know how to make it so that when K5 is clicked IN PROGRESS shows in M5 and time shows in O5 without making each individual macro and coding each individual cell, which I think takes up the same amount of space in memory. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Example for "clickable cells" mentioned in my first comment

> *...If columns A to K contain data, I'd make columns L to O clickable*
>   *(distinct background color as well), using SelectionChange() event*
>   *allows you to determine the coordinates of each cell, and to build*
>   *specific actions depending on current row*

---

Place this `Sub` in **`ThisWorkbook`** module

```
Option Explicit

'In ThisWorkbook module - Sh parameter contains the sheet being used (ActiveSheet)
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        Select Case Sh.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"   'Processing the first 3 sheets
                If .Row > 1 And .CountLarge = 1 Then 'Ignore Headers & multiple cells
                    Select Case .Column
                        Case 1 To 4         'Ignore col A to D
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 204)    'Revert to initial
                            .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic  'Default Black
                        Case 5              'Mouse clicked in a cell in col E
                            With Sh.Cells(.Row, "A")    'Change cell in same row, col A
                                .Interior.Color = RGB(190, 0, 0)    'Dark Red
                                .Font.Color = vbYellow
                            End With
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)    'Light Yellow
                            .Font.Color = vbRed     'current cell (in column E)
                            .Font.Bold = True
                        Case 6              'Mouse clicked in a cell in col F
                            With Sh.Cells(.Row, "B")    'Change cell in same row, col B
                                .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 190)    'Dark Blue
                                .Font.Color = vbYellow
                            End With
                            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)    'Light Yellow
                            .Font.Color = vbRed
                            .Font.Bold = True
                        Case 7              'Mouse clicked in a cell in col G
                            If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then
                                With Sh.Cells(.Row, "C")    'Cell in same row, col B
                                    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)  'vbYellow
                                    .Font.Color = RGB(190, 0, 0)        'Dark Red
                                End With
                            End If
                        Case 8
                            .Value = Format(Now, "ddd mm-dd-yyyy")
                            .Font.Bold = True
                            .Offset(, 1).Value2 = "In Progress"
                    End Select
                End If
            Case "Sheet4", "Sheet5"
                '...
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.

Result, after clicking individual cells in columns E to H

---

**`Sheet1`**

[image: Sheet1]

**`Sheet2`**

[image: Sheet2]

**`Sheet3`**

[image: Sheet3]

---

.

Another way to detect current selection

---

```
Option Explicit

'In Sheet1 module

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Clicked cell in Column 'A', Row: " & Target.Row
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Message Box when clicking `Sheet1.Cell(A5)`

[image: MsgBoxForA5]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Paul. I ended up going with this:

`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As 
    Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Xit
    If Target.Column = 11 Then
      Cancel = True
      Target.Offset(, 2).Value = "IN PROGRESS"
      Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
    ElseIf Target.Column = 12 Then
      Cancel = True
      Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "COMPLETE"
      Target.Offset(, 4).Value = Time
    ElseIf Target.Column = 14 Then
      Cancel = True
      Target.Offset(, -1).Value = "PARTIAL HOLD"
      Target.Offset(, 3).Value = Time
    End If
    Xit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub`